# Cast to ObjectId failed for value (type Object) at path "_id" for model "User" in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Am trying to use the `userId` from the Params to fetch that particular user friends.

```js
    router.get("/friends/:userId", async (req, res) => {
    try {
    const user = await User.findById({userId:req.params.userId});
    const friends = await Promise.all(
      user.following.map((friendId) => {
        return User.findById(friendId);
      })
     );
    let friendList = [];
    friends.map((friend) => {
      const { _id, username, profilePicture } = friend;
      friendList.push({ _id, username, profilePicture });
    });
    res.status(200).json(friendList)
    console.log(friendList)
    } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
    console.log(err)
    }
    });
```

But I get this error

```
    CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ userId: '61543261597a97bfdf670f0b' }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "User"
```

friends data in my when I Log it out to see...

```json
    [
    undefined,
    {
    _id: new ObjectId("6154346027ecc696433f5b86"),
    username: 'Hemmyhtec',
    email: 'emmmmaee@gmail.com',
    password: '$2b$10$wVkZGu4PxlmW3geXfeBwHOxGeK6v7wyjyV7xeLzBNWQSeg5LtA.eW',
    profilePicture: 'logo3.jpg',
    coverPicture: '',
    followers: [ '', '61543261597a97bfdf670f0b' ],
    following: [ '' ],
    isAdmin: false,
    createdAt: 2021-09-29T09:39:44.199Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-10-02T20:25:38.569Z,
    __v: 0
   }
   ]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `findById()`, your should pass only the value of the `_id` and not the object `userId` with that value. Change your code like this:

```js
const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId);
```

Comment: Have tried that also but same error

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
user.following.map((friendId) => {
return User.findById(friendId);
```

})

with

```
user.following.map((friendId) => {
if(!friendId) return
return User.findById(friendId);
```

})

Comment: Didnt work giving same error.

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: Nodejs, MongoDB and React

Comment: Can you check if `req.params.userId` and `_id` from `friend` are valid object ids?

Comment: I log the both but got no result, it just run that error back... But this is what i have in my data for the logged in user. 

followers: ["6154346027ecc696433f5b86"],
following: [""],
_id: "61543261597a97bfdf670f0b"

Comment: On which line did you log it ? It is crucial in debugging  as it means the error exists on the lines above it.

Comment: ` following: [""], has an `""` which is not valid object id ,

Comment: Okay, Let me add a following manually

Comment: TypeError: Cannot destructure property '_id' of 'friend' as it is undefined.

Comment: I add the user log data in the code